# Typesetting serpentine graphs in LaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, draw

As part of a project I'm doing, I need to typeset serpentine graphs in LaTeX, such as the kind below:

[image]

I also need to draw supplemental graphs such as the one below to help explain serpentine graphs.

[image]

I've previously used `tikz` and `pgfplots` to make graphs, but I haven't found any documentation/tips on drawing graphs like the ones below. Any advice?

Comment: welcome to tex.se! well, we are not service "do-it-for-me", therefore show what you try so far and where you stuck in your efforts.

Answer (score 9):

Here is a code for a serpentine graph in `pstricks`:

```
\documentclass[border=3pt, svgnames]{standalone}

\usepackage{pstricks-add, pst-arrow}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf} % to compile with pdflatex

\begin{document}
\psset{xunit=1.5cm, yAxis = false, arrowinset=0.12, ticks=none, labels=none}

\footnotesize
\begin{pspicture}
    \psaxes{->}(-1,0)(6.5,0)[$s$, 120][,0]
    \dotnodes[dotstyle=|, dotsize=6pt](0,0){O}(0.3,0){a}(2.8,0){d}(4.15,0){c}(5.5,0){b}
    \pnode(6.2,2.6){E}
    \foreach \N/\L in {O/0,a/3,b/55,c/41.5,d/28}{\uput{2ex}[d](\N){\L}}
    \psset{dotstyle=*, dotsize=3pt, unit=5mm}
    \foreach \N/\P[count=\i] in {a/A,b/B,c/C,d/D}{\nput*[labelsep=\i]{90}{\N}{\dotnode{\P}}}%
    \nput*[labelsep=2.8]{0}{A}{\pnode{A1}}
    \nput*[labelsep=1.8]{180}{C}{\pnode{C1}}
    \uput[l](A){$t = 0$}\uput[r](B){$t =2$}\uput[u](C){$t =\frac{7}{2}$}\uput[l](D){$t = 5$}%
    \psset{linewidth=1.2pt, linecolor=DeepSkyBlue, linearc=0.8, angleB=-90, armB=0, }
    \ncangle{A}{B}\ncline[arrows=->]{A}{A1}
    \ncangle[angleA=180]{C}{D}\ncline[arrows=->]{C}{C1}
    \psset{angleA=90, armA=0,angleB=0, linecolor=DeepPink}
    \ncangle{B}{C}
    \ncangle[arrows=->, angleB=180]{D}{E}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

*Edit:* A code for the second graph

```
\documentclass[border=3pt, svgnames]{standalone}

\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf} % to compile with pdflatex

\begin{document}

\psset{ yAxis = false, arrowinset=0.12, ticks=none, labels=none}
\footnotesize
\begin{pspicture}
    \psaxes{->}(-1,0)(7,0)[$t$, 120][,0]
    \dotnodes[dotstyle=|, dotsize=4pt, linewidth=0.4pt](0,3pt){O}(2,3pt){a}(3.5,3pt){b}(5,3pt){c}
    \foreach \N/\L in {O/0,a/2,b/\frac{7}{2},c/5}{\uput[u](\N){$\L$}}
    \uput[d](a){$0$}\uput[d](c){$0$}
    \ncline[nodesep=2pt, offset=-8pt, linecolor=DeepPink, linewidth=0.7pt, linestyle=dashed, dash=3.5pt 2.5pt]{a}{c}
    \psset{linecolor=DeepSkyBlue, linestyle=none, showpoints, plotpoints=8, dotstyle=+}
    \psplot{0}{1.8}{-0.18}
    \psplot{5.2}{6.8}{-0.18}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 also to you. I often vote positive your answers.

Answer (score 3):

The following is a possible way to draw your graphs with `tikz`.

First graph:

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\tikzset{
    mynode/.style={draw, circle, fill=black,
        inner sep=0pt,
        minimum width=4pt},
    myline/.style={very thick, rounded corners=9},
    mydecor/.style={postaction={decorate, decoration={markings,mark=at position #1 with {\arrow{Stealth};}}}},
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[-Stealth] (-7mm,0) -- (70mm, 0);
    \foreach \pos/\id in {0/A, 3/B, 28/C, 41.5/D, 55/E}{
        \draw (\pos mm,0) -- (\pos mm, 2mm);
        \node at (\pos mm,-3mm) (\id) {\pos};
    }
    \node[mynode, label=left:{$t=5$}, above=14pt of B] (start) {};
    \node[mynode, label=right:{$t=2$}, above=26pt of E] (second) {};
    \node[mynode, label=above:{$t=\frac{7}{2}$}, above=38pt of D] (third) {};
    \node[mynode, label=left:{$t=5$}, above=50pt of C] (fourth) {};
    \draw[
    myline, cyan,
    mydecor={0.25},
    ] (start) -| (second); 
    \draw[myline, red] (second) |- (third); 
    \draw[myline, cyan,
    mydecor={0.5},
    ] (third) -| (fourth);
    \draw[myline, -Stealth, red] (fourth) -- ++ (0,12pt) -- ++ (42mm,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

[image]

Second graph:

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\tikzset{
    plusdecor/.style={          
        cyan,
        postaction={
            decorate, decoration={
                markings,
                mark=between positions 0 and 1 step .73em with{\node[font=\tiny] {$\bm{+}$};}
            }
        }
    },
    minusdecor/.style={
        red,
        postaction={
            decorate, decoration={
                markings,
                mark=between positions 0 and 1 step .73em with{\node[font=\tiny] {$\bm{-}$};}
            }
        }
    },
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[-Stealth,very thick] (-7mm,0) -- (70mm, 0);
    \foreach \pos/\id/\descr in {0/AA/0, 20/BB/2, 35/CC/{\raisebox{8.6pt}{$\frac{7}{2}$}}, 50/DD/5
    }{
        \draw (\pos mm,0) -- (\pos mm, 2mm);
        \node at (\pos mm,5mm) (\id) {\descr};
    }
    \node at (68mm,3mm) {$t$};
    \node[below=8pt of BB] (belowBB) {$0$};
    \node[below=8pt of DD] (belowDD) {$0$};
    \path[plusdecor] (belowBB) -- +(-22mm, 0);
    \path[minusdecor] (belowBB) -- (belowDD);
    \path[plusdecor] (belowDD) -- +(18mm,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It all looks very nice. However, could you explain how to make the 180° turns into perfect half-circles? (At the moment it looks like the width of the node/bullet might be the problem. Could one use the centre of the node as anchor for the path?)

Comment: @Earthliŋ Sorry, I don't completely understand your question. My intention wasn't to make a perfect half-circle turns, but only a path with rounded corners.

Comment: I see. My question was whether there is a way to make perfect half-circle turns.

Comment: +1 always for all friends....and for your excellent work.

Comment: @Earthliŋ Of course there is, you could draw an `arc`, but I don't think it's necessary in this particular example. If you would like you could ask a follow up question :)

Comment: @Sebastiano Thank you, always remember to vote the post, not the poster!